# SSL error while running syncdb on Django with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ssl

I am running a Django project with PostgreSQL (postgresql_psycopg2) on a shared host (using fcgi). To clarify: I am currently not using SSL.

After deploying my project and running `python manage.py syncdb` on the command-line, I get the following error:

```
"OperationalError: received invalid response to SSL negotiation: 2"
```

This is the message I see on every debug page whenever I try to connect to the DB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Must define the host to 'localhost'. That solved the issue.

Comment: Do you mean the hostname as in /etc/hostname?

Answer (score 6):

Also make sure you're not using the port number for MySQL but the one for postgres. Maybe I'm the only one silly enough to do that...

Comment: That makes two of us. The correct Postgres port to use is 5432